# classnotfound exception when deploying scala class on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, scala, noclassdeffounderror

When I attempt to deploy a Scala class to GAE I receive this error in the logs :

Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Predef$
    at com.myapp.controller.FirstTest.getString(FirstTest.scala:7)
    at com.gogofindit.myapp.RedirectController.displaySearch(RedirectController.java:20)

The app works locally, its just when I deploy to app engine that I receive the error.

According to this doc Scala is supported : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/

Here is the Scala class :

```
class FirstTest {

  def getString = {

    println("In scala")

    "search"
  }

}
```

Do I need to update a config file within the project so that the Scala classes are compiled ?

Comment: Do you have scala library on the classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala is supported without any additional effort.
But your scala classes should be added to compile process, either in pom.xml or in project config (by adding nature in Eclipse for instance). 
Take a look if you can find compiled classes in bin/ or target/classes, next to java classes.

Comment: yes the Scala is being compiled locally, is there something I need to update so that the class is compiled on GAE prod ?

Comment: Not at all, you compile nothing on GAE prod, just need to deploy war, let say. so as long as in your war in WEB-INF/classes you can find your scala stuff, everything should be send to GAE. Does everything work on dev server?

Comment: And you have a scala library in classpath but are you sure you have it in WEB-INF/lib in your final war too? Because your scala class is found and invoked actually. What is not found is scala.Predef - object from scala standard library.

Comment: yes that was my issue, I was'nt aware that the files in web-inf/lib were actually deployed to appengine. So GAE checks this folder when trying to compile the scala classes ?

Comment: no, scala classes are already compiled. only at runtime you are using method println which is defined in scala.Predef object. this one is in scala-library.jar and GAE was looking for it in standard place: WEB-INF/lib.